# UIButton background image not changing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to change button background image as per the web service response. if in response I get   unread messages to true then image will different and if there is no unread messages image will be different. I am getting the response very well but not able to change my button's background image.

This is the snippet I am using

```
if(unread>0){
    [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else{
    [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"read.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Your Button should be "Custom Button".

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what value unread assumes? Maybe the problem is that it doesn't have the value that you expect. A bit more of context, showing more source code would help.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I already debugged it and it is goes in right condition but cant change the image. dont know why

Comment: Did you set image in xib? remove them or set only background image in xib and try again please if you did.

Comment: yes I set image in xib @yucelbayram. wait I will check that

Comment: setting in code is the latest working option ,so setting in xib i dont think is a factor

Comment: The UIControlState parameter is not a bitmask, you should call the method twice for UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateSelected.

Comment: but @yucelbayram it doesnt make sense because if i remove the background from xib it will give me right image after that but when i click i again want to change but it is not changing.

Comment: @BaZinga you need to reload the view for it or on button press you have to change the unread message value

Comment: [badgeTitle setSelected:YES];

Comment: @BaZinga mate paste your button image changer code in viewDidload and check if its working code please.

Comment: no in view did load its also not changing. please help me guyzzzz

Comment: check IBOutlet connection of your button :)

Comment: viewDidLoad load only once the view is load you need to call the view again i think

Comment: @iphonemaclover yes it load once , i just said it for check it out code working or not because if image going to change once than its easy to change it again with if and else statements in button actions or wherever you want, you know.

Comment: In .xib put read.png as background image to your button. Then add following to your code;

if(unread>0){
    [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

Comment: you are right @yucelbayram  thats why set background image method is there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution can be very simple, if you look at it.
Keep a global UIButton and not a local one. This helps, as when the web request returns back a response, the button needs to be present in-scope and not get removed from the memory.

*So use*,

```
self.myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[self.myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**OR**

```
[self.myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

*And, if you checking on the click of a button, then follow the steps* :

```
-(IBAction)checkForMsgCount: (id)sender
{
  UIButton *buttonObj = (UIButton*)sender;

[buttonObj setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

This changes the background image, for the button that is responding to the function.

Comment: that doesnt make any sense and I debug for so many time if button is removed or not but it is there all the time.

Comment: the solution indicates clearly, that you need to be clear, as to WHAT button is responding to the method. This can be used by, type casting the sender object, to a UIButton, and then changing the image to it.  TRY THIS and TELL IF IT DOES NOT WORK

Comment: I have myself used this. Telling you, it will work. Just try it !

Answer (score 1):

```
[YourBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

try it please.

Can you also try this for check it out if you really have this pictures in your bundle ?

```
        NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString *imagePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s/yourButton.png", [bundlePath  UTF8String]];


if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]) {
    NSLog(@"image exists");
}
else{
    NSlog(@"image Does Not Exist");
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

please try code below

```
if(unread>0){
    [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"] forState :UIControlStateSelected];
}
else{
    [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"read.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"read.png"] forState :UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

Comment: He wanted to change it for both UIControlState selected and normal. You should call the method twice to add the image for these two control states. Also, you should give some explanation for this code and for what the user was doing wrong.

Comment: yes it will work please check if you only want to change only for UIControlStateNormal it will work

Comment: why dont you put forstate in second line?

Comment: oh it just syntax error please add this when you apply this code

Answer (score 0):

**First check IBOutlet connection of your button :)**

And set your code after getting data from web service  i.e. after getting value of `unread`

```
if(unread>0){
    [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else{
    [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"read.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: and it is in "or" with UIControlStateNormal. and BTW with just only UIControlStateNormal it is not working

Comment: check IBOutlet connection of your button :)

Comment: then make a new button from starting :)

Comment: dude many time this will work to remove previous object and make new

Answer (score 0):

```
[badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateSelected];
```

are you adding the button image for `UIControlStateNormal` or `UIControlStateSelected`

try

```
[badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

find whether the image exist and added properly to the bundle and The name is correct

Comment: image is exist @Lithu

Comment: @BaZinga try setting image in two lines for controlstate normal and selected

Comment: @BaZinga since you are setting foe selected do try setting image for unselected state

Answer (score 0):

Set background images for UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateSelected as **separate lines**.

```
if(unread>0){

   [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"] UIControlStateNormal];

   [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"] UIControlStateSelected];
} else {

   [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"read.png"] UIControlStateNormal];

   [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"read.png"] UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

Comment: Correct, but please at least add some explanation.

Comment: same answer as above posted !

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 50);
    [btn setTitle:@"ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
```

I hope this works for u....

Comment: try this, 
if(unread.text.length>0){
    [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else{
    [badgeTitle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"read.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if unread is string then this is works...

Answer (score 0):

after setting the background image

```
[badgeTitle setNeedsLayout];
```